# Finding the general term of $(x+my) ^ 8$ (binomial expansion)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the general term in the expansion of $(x+my) ^ 8$?

Been trying to solve this for quite awhile but keep messing up on the expansions, hope someone can help me in this, many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT : You can use this.

$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k.$$

$$(x+my)^8=\sum_{k=0}^{8}\binom{8}{k}x^{8-k}{(my)}^k=\sum_{k=0}^{8}\binom{8}{k}x^{8-k}y^km^k.$$

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in this case, the varying term is actually m, so will it be the same if I were to use this formula? Many thanks :)

Comment: You mean $m$ is a variable, $x,y$ are constants?

Comment: Oh actually I mean x and y are still algebraic terms, but m will be the one that will be used for the varying term of the general term.

e.g. 1+2+3+4+....nth term , the general term is n(n+1)/2

Comment: @Freeman: You can use the formula above. See my answer.

Comment: hmm? +1+1=1? :)

Comment: I'm just gonna go out on a limb and say that the OP hasnt upvoted it yet..

Comment: I am very sorry I am a new user here, and I am unable to vote up this answer as it requires 15 rep points, but I have click on "accept answer", really sorry, but thanks for the help here :)

Comment: It's no problem really @Freeman.

Comment: It's no problem really @Freeman:)